# Meaning of negative voltage

Tags: voltage, basic

When solving for circuit consists of  ideal voltages and conventional resistors I get that one of the resistor's voltage is negative- does it mean the resistor delivers power, or the polarity of the resistor need to be changed?

Comment: It would be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltage is measured *relative* to something.

Say you measure the speed of a train coming toward you. If it is approaching at 50 km/h, you could express that as a positive value: +50.

If you again were to measure its speed as it leaves, from the same *point of reference* you would say it is departing at 50 km/h, but you could express this as a negative value: -50.

Voltage is the same way, depending on what your reference point is to ground, you might measure voltages as being either positive or negative.

Comment: @ JYelton But resistor can't deliver power, can it?

Comment: @user7777777 No it certainly can't. Except under some very interesting hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: @user7777777 No, a resistor is a *passive* component. It simply resists the flow of current.

Comment: @user7777777 If JYelton's answer answers your question, mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage across a resistor is the voltage at one end minus the voltage at the other end.  In some contexts, it may make sense to describe the voltage as being the higher voltage minus the lower one, but in other contexts the selection of which end should be subtracted is dictated by other factors.  For example, if two or more components or groups thereof are considered to be in parallel, the ends should match so that both components are considered to have equal voltages of the same polarity.  If two or more components or groups thereof are considered to be in series, the common node(s) voltages should be added from one component's value but added to the next so as not to affect the total.  Note that the scenario where exactly two two-terminal components are connected to each other at both ends may be viewed as either a series or parallel connection.